# It says student_id doesn't exist in table, but it does?

Tags: mysql

It says student_id doesn't exist, but it's clearly there, I just want to connect these tables together. (Mysql 5.7)

[image]

Comment: Please add you issue in text (code) not as an image. Also : i don't see a student_id column in your table. it just isn't there.

Comment: The error is that student_id does not exist in subject.

Comment: Please include your error messages in your question, so StackOverflow can find similar question automatically and we copy-paste it to look for relevant information. Follow this link for more information: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I suspect you need to create a junction table - studentid, subjectid

Comment: MySQL is always right with error messages... `FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)` = `FOREIGN KEY ([local_table_column]) REFERENCES [parent_table]([parent_table_column])` your table Subject doenst have a local column named student_id

Comment: @nanne Take it easy, clearly Jin is new in the site and maybe doesnt know the way we work here. So you can give more constructive comment to help her feel welcome in the site.

Comment: What do you mean, more constructive? I have not only given a comment, I have also added what should be done to remedy the situation. This is the basis of constructive. I even answered the question, and given a hint what type of addition would have made me give a better solution. You seem to be easily 'offended' in name of someone else. I see no need for that.

Comment: @Nanne Calling a person Lazy is very rude. Not matter what scenario. Im not offended, but know what feel be new in a site and have that kind of treatment.

Comment: @Jin Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: It's not a compliment, I admit, but it is also true. It is not a "I didn't know" sort of mistake, it's just the easiest way out. I think it is valid to call things by their name, and if one is (percieved as) lazy I think there is no problem to put that in to words. I don't consider it rude. I DO consider it rude to expect everyone to be willing to go the extra mile.....

Comment: @Nanne You dont have to go the extra mile. But you dont have to go the wrong route neither. Just think about it, she a new member and you can give her the benefit of the doubt. Im just saying your comment would be perfect until the last sentence.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well, I respectfully disagree with you on that.

Comment: @Nanne You dont have to agree with me, just with the forum [**guidelines**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  `Lazy` fall into name calling category. And if you do not have the time, leave it for someone who does..

Answer (score 0):

That's because you doesn't create student_id in subject table
you must create student_id after subject_id column

Answer (score 0):

student_id is missing on your Subject table, add `student_id int unsigned not null` in your query to create Subject table before you put the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the column 'student_id' in the 'subject' table. The error denotes the 'subject' table.

You are trying to mark a column 'student_id' in 'subject' table as foreign key that references to column 'student_id' in 'students' table.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments you `Subjects` Table doesnt have `student_id` field, and probably shouldnt have it. Otherwise you would be repeating the same data for each student attending that course.

So what you do:

- Create the Tables `Students`, `Subjects` like you have it now (without the foreign key to `Student`)
- Create a junction table `student_subject` `{subject_id, student_id}` where you store what subjects are enrolled each student.

  - Create Foreign keys to `Students`, `Subjects`

Then if you want get what subjects is enrolled one student.

```
 SELECT st.*, su.*
 FROM Students st
 JOIN Student_Subjects ss      
   ON st.student_id = ss.student_id
 JOIN Subjects su
   ON ss.subject_id = su.subject_id
 WHERE st.student_id = @student_id
```